# Custom 404 pages using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

hi guys can you help be me

im having a problem in ridecting my customize 404 error page

this my **htaccess code:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 

   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d


   RewriteRule ^home index.php [NC,L]

   RewriteRule ^works works.php [NC,L]

   RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) category.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]

   ErrorDocument 404 /404.html


</IfModule>
```

can help to fixed this prpblem

**this is the ERROR**

Not Found

The requested URL /fur/cate was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9 Server at localhost Port 8080

Comment: Your page `/404.html` is not in a sepecial directory like `/errors/` ?

Comment: yes is not a sepecial directory

Comment: And you can see the page with `http://www.domain.com/404.html` ?

Comment: yes but im having a problem in redirecting it. i cant see the 404.html

Comment: _redirecting it_ but where is the real page ?

Comment: Move your `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` after `</IfModule>`. I do not think it's that, but it is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to HTTPS
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
#RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond $1 !^(cron\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

override this file